# How do you point an eclipse project to a specific AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I've looked at the android documentation, there is nothing about changing which virtual device any one project uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup up Eclipse project to let you manually select what devices to publish/debug your app on. I do this for all my devices. Select the arrow next to the debug icon and select "Debug Configurations". Then select the "Target" tab and select the radio button "Always prompt to pick device".

This may be what you are are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure on which device you prefer your project to run. Go into the `Run Configurations` under Android select the `Target` tab. Check `Automatically pick compatible device....` and choose your preferred device!!